# Collapse of description: Filter criteria syntax example of BubbleNode.Search

Tags: documentation, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Please update the example that is filter criteria syntax of BubbleNode.Search.

It's here:

1. API References https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/BubbleNode/
2. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0252.png

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out and I've let the contents management team know to put this right

Comment: Thank you for your actions.